# how i can import the websocket library to eclipse(android)

Tags: android, eclipse, websocket

i work with eclipse and i want to use websocket in my project and i find this project on internet:

http://www.elabs.se/blog/66-using-websockets-in-native-ios-and-android-apps

but project is for android studio and i dont know how i can import dependencies and other files in correct place.
please tell me how i can use websocket?
i don't want to use socket instead of websocket because of my friend write all things in php and we don't want to use js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the blog post and followed the example you will see that he uses the `Java-websocket` library.

Their jar releases are here: https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/releases

A good way to add external JARs to your Android project or any Java project is:

1. Create a folder called `libs` in your project's root folder
2. Copy your JAR files to the `libs` folder
3. Now **right click on the Jar file and then select Build Path > Add to Build Path**, which will create a folder called 'Referenced Libraries' within your project

By doing this, **you will not lose your libraries** that are being referenced on your hard drive whenever you transfer your project to another computer.